# I want to split a long equation in many lines

Tags: split

I have a long line in equation. I want to split it properly in two or three lines.
I've been using `\begin{split}` and `\end{split}`, but still it is not in good position. The equation's code is below.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{r(r-1)c_{0}}{z} + \\ &  \sum_{0}^{\infty}[[(j+r)(j+r+1)c_{j+1} - [(j+r)(j+r-1) - l(l+1)]c_{j}] \\ &= 0,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: (i) please help us to help you: provide complete but small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. it is not fun to write from scratch missing part of code (which can be also essential), especially you already have this code ... (ii) welcome to tex.se!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's not clear what you mean with "in a good position" ...

one solution using `split` can be:

[image]

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&       \frac{r(r-1)c_{0}}{z} + \sum_{0}^{\infty}\Bigl[(j+r)(j+r+1)c_{j+1}    \\
&\qquad  - [(j+r)(j+r-1) - l(l+1)]c_{j}\Bigr] = 0,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

**addedndum:**

solution as you like to have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mamsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&   \frac{r(r-1)c_{0}}{z} + \sum_{0}^{\infty}\Bigl[(j+r)(j+r+1)c_{j+1}    \\
&   - [(j+r)(j+r-1) - l(l+1)]c_{j}\Bigr] = 0,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

another solution (which I like the most) is with use of the package `mathtools` and its environment `multlined`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{multlined}[0.7\linewidth]
\frac{r(r-1)c_{0}}{z} + \sum_{0}^{\infty}\Bigl[(j+r)(j+r+1)c_{j+1}    \\
- [(j+r)(j+r-1) - l(l+1)]c_{j}\Bigr] = 0,
    \end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good position means that second line should start from the same position below the first.

Comment: @NoorAslam "Good position" is very subjective: for example, I would move the second line even further to the right, and starting both lines from the very left seems quite bad to me for _this_ equation (personal opinion). In summary: please edit the question and make your requirement explicit `:-)`

Comment: ok, than erase `\qquad` in my code ... however, i agree with @campa comment

Comment: @Zarko you have more experience than me in latex. I apperiate your opinion. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Using `geometry` for decent margins, it can fit on two lines:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{r(r-1)c_{0}}{z} &{}+ \sum_{0}^{\infty}\Bigl[(j+r)(j+r+1)c_{j+1} - [(j+r)(j+r-1) - l(l+1)]c_{j}\Bigr] \\ &= 0,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

[image]